# my flutter app is not install from play store after update the new version in play store

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-update

After update my app 9 (1.0.10) to 10 (1.0.11) & i used [in_app_update: ^4.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update) package to detect the app update but when i open my app after the update it show me update dialog  try to update the app but it don't get any update in the app then I try to update from play store so I get this error

[image]

I do research but can't find anything helpful for me I am already using android:exported="true" in my manifest file that I saw many people facing this issue and get resolved by adding this line but I am already using this line in my app and my compile SDK version is 33 and min SDK is 21

Comment: were you able to solve it? I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: no i have realise another version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app not able to update on Google Play Store (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658506/flutter-app-not-able-to-update-on-google-play-store-android)